# How to remove both whitespace and new line in Regex

Tags: regex, newline, whitespace

I have a text string like:

Function:
General Business

So after "Function:" there is a bit of whitespace, then a new line. I have created an API to a website and need to do some Regex to just get "General Business" as a string.

At the moment my regex is `/(Function: )(\s?)(.*)`. However, this will not return me anything. I don't know where to fit `\n` into the Regex to also move down to the next line and pick up "General Business".

Any ideas? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a space character and following it with optional whitespace, you can use:

```
Function:\s+(.*)
```

`\s` matches any white space character, `+` means match the preceding "one or more" times.